# When we need return value from trigger procedure?

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers, postgresql-9.6

Documentation about trigger procedures  (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) says: "A trigger function must return either NULL or a record/row".

Example

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE some_trigger_function();
```

Suppose `some_trigger_function()` returns record/row, I understood that procedure body is called and executed on this event, on this table, and so on... but where returns value this procedure?

Question is: when we use that returned value? why we needed this value at all? Can you give little example/explanation, which uses this returned value?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Read in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/trigger-definition.html):

> Trigger functions invoked by per-statement triggers should always
>   return NULL. Trigger functions invoked by per-row triggers can return
>   a table row (a value of type HeapTuple) to the calling executor, if
>   they choose. A row-level trigger fired before an operation has the
>   following choices:
>
> - It can return NULL to skip the operation for the current row. This instructs the executor to not perform the row-level operation that
>     invoked the trigger (the insertion, modification, or deletion of a
>     particular table row).
> - For row-level INSERT and UPDATE triggers only, the returned row becomes the row that will be inserted or will replace the row being
>     updated. This allows the trigger function to modify the row being
>     inserted or updated.
>
> A row-level BEFORE trigger that does not intend to cause either of
>   these behaviors must be careful to return as its result the same row
>   that was passed in (that is, the NEW row for INSERT and UPDATE
>   triggers, the OLD row for DELETE triggers).
>
> A row-level INSTEAD OF trigger should either return NULL to indicate
>   that it did not modify any data from the view's underlying base
>   tables, or it should return the view row that was passed in (the NEW
>   row for INSERT and UPDATE operations, or the OLD row for DELETE
>   operations). A nonnull return value is used to signal that the trigger
>   performed the necessary data modifications in the view. This will
>   cause the count of the number of rows affected by the command to be
>   incremented. For INSERT and UPDATE operations, the trigger may modify
>   the NEW row before returning it. This will change the data returned by
>   INSERT RETURNING or UPDATE RETURNING, and is useful when the view will
>   not show exactly the same data that was provided.
>
> The return value is ignored for row-level triggers fired after an
>   operation, and so they can return NULL.

The below example shows how to conditionally abort insertion in a trigger:

```
create table my_table(id int);

-- do not insert rows with id > 10
create or replace function before_insert_on_my_table()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    return case
        when new.id > 10 then null
        else new
    end;
end $$;

create trigger before_insert_on_my_table
before insert on my_table
for each row execute procedure before_insert_on_my_table();

insert into my_table
values (15), (10), (5), (20)
returning id;

 id 
----
 10
  5
(2 rows)
```